# ESXi with 1 vSwitch using multiple teamed NICs each connected on a seperate physical switch for resilience/redundancy

Tags: switch, vmware-esx, nic, vswitch, network-teaming

I've read many posts (even from vmware) saying that in ESXi, NICs teamed in a vSwitch should all be connected to the same physical switch.
I found nothing about what I am describing below and in my opinion, this infringes the resilience/redundancy goal we all want to achieve.

If a datacenters, there is a bunch of switches uplinked one to another via a trunk port so it permits hundreds of NICs connection to the LAN.
I am far from being a network expert but my understanding is if all switches that are unlinked together have the same native vlan configured for the ports on wich all ESX nics are connected, then for me it is considered being in the same network/broadcast domain and it should work just fine.
It may be a bit exagerated but for example, this should allow us to lets say connect 4 teamed nics of the same ESX vSwitch on 4 different physical switches (having the same native vlan) to achieve a very robust redundancy plan in case of network/switches failure.

Am i wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect host NICs to multiple switches any way you like.

If you use a failover scheme or load balance between NICs then you must configure the switch ports alike (native/untagged VLAN, tagged VLANs).

Of course, the switches need to be trunked together with all relevant VLANs, and you should make sure there's sufficient bandwidth, regardless of which ports are active.